# Make clickable div open the URL in a new page

Tags: html

So, I am making a website and I wanted to make the div clickable, instead of using the anchor tag.
I did it like this: `<div onClick="location.href='URL';"` and it worked, but I want it to open the URL in a new page. I tried adding `target="_blank"` but unfortunately it didn't work.
Does anyone know how to do it or if it's possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div onClick="window.open('URL', '_blank').focus();"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, it works, only thing is that the text inside the div goes into the next line. I want it to be on the same one. I tried to apply "white-space: nowrap" to the class I gave to the div but it still won't work. Any idea?

Comment: `white-space: nowrap` should works. Can you show me full code. May be `div` element located inside `div` with `display: flex` ?

Comment: Oh don't worry, I fixed it, I used display: inline